# How to add latest TLS certificate for https communication in lollipop apps

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-security

I want to add latest TLS certificates to my android app(Which should be supported by 5.1 Lillipop + versions).

I have added TLS certificate for my previous versions,but some 5.1 versions are failing to establish https communication due to TLS certificate.

Please help me out to get TLS certificate issue.Thankq in advance.

Comment: Provide more information of TLS issue such as error message, error code , logs...

Comment: Please refer this link to enable TLS protocol. http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/